# How to create a Shared object with also another .SO in Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I have shared object that I create in Cmake, but I need to link it to another .so file. 
how do I do that?
this is my CMakeList.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(DAL VERSION 1.0.1 DESCRIPTION "DAL - Data Access Layer this class connect with the sql data base throw the Connection class")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
add_library(DAL SHARED
        src/AppSettingDAL.cpp
        src/AppSettingEntity.cpp
        src/SettingsModificationDAL.cpp
        src/SymbolDAL.cpp
        src/SymbolInfoEntity.cpp
        )

set_target_properties(DAL PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        SOVERSION 1
        PUBLIC_HEADER
        include/AppSettingsDAL.hpp
        include/SettingsModificationDAL.hpp
        include/AppSettingEntity.hpp
        include/SymbolDAL.hpp
        include/SymbolInfoEntity.hpp
        )
configure_file(DAL.pc.in DAL.pc @ONLY)
target_include_directories(DAL PRIVATE .)
install(TARGETS DAL
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/DAL.pc DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/pkgconfig)
```

and I want it to link to lib connlib.so

Answer (score 0):

```
add_executable(DAL ...)
target_link_libraries(DAL connlib)
```

(NOTE: Do not include the EXT. It would be completed by cmake base on your OS.)